# Character by character for input

Tags: python

So i tried to use this delay code to use it with input. But i couldn't figure it out. It always writes without delay. How can i fix it ?

```
import time

def print_character_by_character(text, delay=0.1):
    for char in text:
        print(char, end="", flush=True)
        time.sleep(delay)

text_to_print = "Hello"
print_character_by_character(text_to_print)
```

Comment: How are you running the code? For me, the delay is working as intended.

Comment: it works with print but it doesn't work with input. Is there a way to use it also with input ?

Comment: I'm not sure how it is supposed to work with input. Do you want to block entering characters until delay passes? Please provide a clearer example of expected behaviour.

Comment: It writes without delay when asking for an input. I want an input after "Hello" delay works with "Hello" but not when i ask for an input

Comment: I'm new to python. Sorry if i couldn't express the question well

Comment: Soo... just print with delay and call input with no text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a way or make one:

```
import time

def input_character_by_character(text, delay=0.1):
    for char in text:
        print(char, end="", flush=True)
        time.sleep(delay)
    return input(":")

text_to_print = "Hello"
s = input_character_by_character(text_to_print)
```